# How to build and install rails application dependencies on different hosts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rubygems, bundler

I have a rails 3 application that I'd like to deploy. My deployment environment does not have build tools installed and cannot then install dependencies with native extensions.

I have a build host configured with build tools that can build the native extensions.

How can I deploy the native extensions from my build host ?

I have tried doing `bundle package` on the build host and `bundle install --local` on the remote host. It correctly installs gems without native extensions but it still tries to build native extensions on the production host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up to a custom deploy.rb. Hoping I will be able to relase it as a gem that extends Capistrano (still not totally happy with it though)

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to build on your production servers.

When I deploy Django or Rails I always build a toolchain for whatever the OS package management system doesn't cover.  I then develop and deploy with that toolchain.  This assures everyone uses the same versions of the tools.

To create the toolchain you need to install the packages and supporting executables in that directory.  You also need to make sure that they are relocatable.

For example I currently use Django on RedHat.  RedHat doesn't use the latest version of python, and many of the python libs I use rev more often than the repository maintainers pick them up.  As a result there are often no RPMs for the latest software.  I create a toolchain directory, compiled python on all the libs I needed into that directory.  I then bundle it up into an RPM for deployment.

- toolchain/

  - bin/

    - python
    - ...
  - lib/

    - python2.7/
    - ...
    - site-packages/

      - ...
  - include/
  - ...

Comment: Building on the production host is what I am trying to avoid here. That is why I have tried to do `bundle package` on a build host and then to install the package on the production host.

Comment: and then to install the package on the production host. I hoped this will prevent me from building on production host but it still requires building.

Comment: I've had issues with gem installations in the past.  I personally never use gem to install on the production server.  I'll gem install on the build or dev host and repackage it using the native OS packaging system. This allows me better control and more flexible dependency accounting.